# Relationship error

Tags: apex, error

I have a query :

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE Event.DurationInMinutes < 480
```

and I receive following error :

> "Didn't undrstand relationship 'Event' in field path. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom relationship , be sure to append  '__r'
>   after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL  or the
>   desribe call for the appropriate name."

I also used the `Event__r.DurationInMinutes` but I received the same error as well

What I need in this case is to get the name of the employees who had event duration (in minutes) < 480 over the previous day.

I also tried to use the `TODAY -1` but I got an error on that.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to make Aggregate query on Event to get the records.

```
List<AggregateResult> at = [Select Owner.Name, SUM(DurationInMinutes) from EVENT WHERE DurationInMinutes != null AND DAY_ONLY(startDatetime) = Yesterday group by Owner.Name];
```

This query will give you result based on previous day and you can check the size of `DurationInMinutes` as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tushar, this is not working. I created a new query using the query you used but i get an error "Can only query Event". Bear in mind that I use this query in jitterbit which uses the SOQL scripts as well.

Comment: @akkiiss55 I do some quick google and I don't think Aggregate query is supported in Jitterbit. Then you might need to break it this query and then use it.

Comment: I used the following : Select Owner.Name, SUM(DurationInMinutes) from EVENT WHERE DurationInMinutes != null AND DAY_ONLY(startDatetime) = Yesterday group by Owner.Name
and i still have the same error

Comment: @akkiiss55 Yes this is aggregate query and this is might not supported.

Comment: so how do I "break it and then use it"?